# How to add a date+1 to a column when the condition is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'Date': ['2020-01-05', '2020-01-03','2020-01-06','2020-01-09'], 'Flag':[1,0,0,1]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

If the flag value is 1, then +1 should be added to the date.  I tried the below code, but it's adding 2 by default.

```
for i in df.Flag:
    df['Result']=pd.to_datetime(df.Date) + pd.DateOffset(days=i+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.loc`

**Ex:**

```
data = {'Date': ['2020-01-05', '2020-01-03','2020-01-06','2020-01-09'], 'Flag':[1,0,0,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.loc[df.Flag == 1, 'Date'] = df['Date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
#OR df['Date'] = np.where(df['Flag'] == 1, df['Date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=1), df['Date'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        Date  Flag
0 2020-01-06     1
1 2020-01-03     0
2 2020-01-06     0
3 2020-01-10     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use apply

```py
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x['Date']) + pd.DateOffset(x['Flag']),axis=1)
```